# Deeplink not work for some messaging app in Android

Tags: android, deep-linking, applinks

I am developing an android app.

It uses AppsFlyer's Onelink kind of a Deeplink.

I set up and tested, in general, it works fine.
When I tested this using Android studio, it works fine
[image]

When I tested this with Slack messenger, it works fine too.

But If I test this with other messaging apps, it doesn't work, and just open the web browser.

I don't know why and how to fix it.

---

```xml
<intent-filter
    android:autoVerify="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:host="mylink.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/path"
        android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

[image]

Comment: what android version you are testing on?

Comment: android 11 and 12

Answer (score 2):

For deep linking to work in Android 12, you need to create `intent-filters` with `autoVerify="true"`

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="https" />
  <data android:scheme="https" />
  <data android:host="www.example.com" />
  <data android:host="mobile.example.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

Host a **Digital Asset Links JSON** on your website at the below location to declare the association between your intent filters and the website.

```
https://your-domain.name/.well-known/assetlinks.json
```

`assertlinks.json` should contain the following information

```
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "your.app.package.name",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["14:6D:E9:83:C5:73:06:50:D8:EE:B9:95:2F:34:FC:64:16:A0:83:42:E6:1D:BE:A8:8A:04:96:B2:3F:CF:44:E5"]
  }
}]
```

You can generate `sha256_cert_fingerprints` using java key tool

```
keytool -list -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
```

If you're using Play App Signing, You can find **Digital Asset Links JSON** snippet at the following location **Release > Setup > App Integrity**

Comment: I already set and check it. I mean it works fine in Slack app, but it doesn't work other message app.

Comment: You should try moving the scheme in separate `data` tag `<data android:scheme="https" />`